# Video recording device detected but can't use it

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, video, devices

I have a StarTech SVID2USB23 device like this: https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/SVID2USB23_Manual/SVID2USB23.pdf

In LSUSB it appears as this:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID eb1a:5051 eMPIA Technology, Inc.
```

After a bit of research I found that the "Ion Video 2 PC MKii" (maybe) uses the same chip (eMPIA EM2860) and there is videos of it working with Linux on Youtube (though the guy seems to build its own Kernel). The "Ion Video 2 PC" also uses 5051 as its ID.

I can't even open the stream in VLC, Cheese or GUVCview, the device is not shown. It doesn't appear anywhere. The device is not faulty because it works on Windows, so Linux is the problem.

If I run dmseg I get this:

```
[  648.960432] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  649.092011] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=eb1a, idProduct=5051
[  649.092014] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[  649.092015] usb 1-8: Product: USB 2861 Device
[  649.092016] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 0
[  706.752960] usbcore: registered new interface driver em28xx
```

Notice that here it says "USB 2861 Device", but in the instruction manual, it says the chip is a eMPIA EM2860.

This driver detects the cards here in the Linux Kernel: /drivers/media/usb/em28xx/em28xx-cards.c
Link: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/media/usb/em28xx/em28xx-cards.c?id=v4.2.3

Around line 2326 I have added

```
{ USB_DEVICE(0xeb1a, 0x5051),
.driver_info = EM2820_BOARD_UNKNOWN },
```

After compiling the Kernel, I saw that the device was now listed as a video device in my programs (VLC, Cheese and GUVCview), but it still didn't work because it couldn't initialize the resolution. "EM2820_BOARD_UNKNOWN" was not the device name to use I guess.

I'd like to get help with this and make it work (not by making changes to the Kernel). There must be some way to make it work without messing with the Kernel. My Kernel is version 3.19, so the driver is already included unlike some older versions.

Thanks,

Alexandre-Xavier

Comment: Update:

I've changed the driver in the Kernel (version 4.2.3) like I did earlier so it recognizes the card.

The good thing to do was to change it for this:
    { USB_DEVICE(0xeb1a, 0x5051),
    .driver_info = EM2860_BOARD_TVP5150_REFERENCE_DESIGN },

Now the device is recognized, but when I go in V4L2 TestBench and start capturing, it captures when the my device is off or when I didn't plug anything to it (when the screen is black), but as soon as I plug my device and it's sending video, the frame counter stops and the device stops capturing. I have not idea how to fix this.

Comment: When my video game console that's connected to my device is turned off, VLC says the "Content bitrate" is 150000 kb/s and the screen is all black. 

When I turn on my device, the only thing I get in VLC is a still picture and the content bitrate now becomes 1537 kb/s.

Comment: This is the new dmesg output:

http://justpaste.it/odqb